# jQuery traversing using closest

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

HTML:

```
<table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="commentLink">
                    <a onclick="ShowBox.call(this); return false;" href="#">Comment</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="commentBox" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="hiddenComment">
                    <textarea class="textComment" rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
                    <input class="foo" type="checkbox" />
                    <input class="commentBtn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addComment.call(this); return false;" />
                    <input class="commentBtn" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="HideBox.call(this); return false;" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JS: using jquery 1.4.2

```
function ShowBox() {
        var that = this;
        $(function () {
            $(".commentBox").show();
            //$(that).closest('tr').siblings().show();
        });
    }
    function HideBox() {
        var that = this;
        $(function () {
            $(that).siblings(".foo").attr("checked", false);
            $(that).siblings(".textComment").empty();
            $(".commentBox").hide();
        });
    }
```

I have the two functions to show/hide a tr. The code I have now works, but it will close other elements too. What is the elegant way of doing this?

Comment: So why don't you use `closest`? Passing a function to `document.ready` inside the functions is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function ShowBox() {
    $(this).closest ('tr').next ('tr.commentBox').show ();
}

function HideBox() {
    var jThis   = $(this);

    jThis.siblings(".foo").attr("checked", false);
    jThis.siblings(".textComment").empty ();
    jThis.closest ('tr.commentBox').hide ();
}
```

BTW, for "elegant", remove the `onclick` attributes from the HTML!

Then add the click functionality with:

```
$('td div.commentLink > a').bind ('click', ShowBox, false);
$('td div.hiddenComment > a.commentBtn[value=Submit]').bind ('click', addComment, false);
$('td div.hiddenComment > a.commentBtn[value=Cancel]').bind ('click', HideBox, false);
```

inside the `$(document).ready ()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `closest` selector was added in version 1.3 I believe, so just use that.